# Which latest JetPack version has Ubuntu 16.02 bundled for Jetson TX2?

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-16.04

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1QDsa6SzuQ

But with JetPack 4.2, there's 18.04 bundled. I don't want that.
Which JetPack version to be used if I need 16.02 on Jetson TX2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a few hours, but I found the answer myself!
If you want Ubuntu 16.04, installation of Jetpack 3.3  is recommended on Jetson TX2. It has Ubuntu 16.04 OS image bundled with it.
All newer versions after V3.3 have Ubuntu 18.04.

For details, check release notes for every JetPack version on this page: https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetpack-archive

Similarly, if you just want plain Ubuntu without any supporting packages like JetPack does, L4T v28.2.1 is the latest version with Ubuntu 16.04.
All newer versions have Ubuntu v18.04.